# Am I allowed to have both a personal and Google Apps account for Google+?

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

My workplace just added Google+ to Google Apps. I already have a personal account, which I want to keep separate from work.

Is having two accounts on Google+ allowed?

Comment: Are you asking if it is allowed technically, or legally according to the Google+ Terms of Service?

Comment: I have two accounts. I'm asking about possible consequences.

Comment: I have three of these now. Consequences so far? Three places I don't bother to post anything interesting instead of just one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google allows Multiple sign-in feature, primarily because of introduction of Google Apps. So managing 2 accounts as in your case should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have both at the moment one with my gmail account and another with my Google Apps account, although I really only use one. Can't see why it wouldn't be ok...